# How to Keep divs in CSS Gallery in Line, or All The Same Size or Both?

Tags: css, gallery

I am working with the code below from w3schools to make a gallery. The problem I have is that if one item has a rather long description it causes the items below to become disordered and not line up properly.

As far as I can tell this can be solved by making the item boxes either all the same height or by having a set gap between each row from the bottom of the tallest on the top row to the top of all three on the bottom row. I do not know how to do either of these.

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here and make it really long to see what happens</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a solution to how they can be kept inline neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:flex` offers a really neat way to organise items like this. You can have everything stretch to the same height as the tallest item in it's row, or you can align them in a bunch of different ways with only a few lines of code to the parent container.
For more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here and make it really long to see what happens</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works well and I want to add one more thing to it. If you want to align the description vertically, you can again use the Flexbox. I have added it in the CSS code here.

```css
.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 180px;
  /* To align the description both horizontally and vertically*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here and make it really long to see what happens</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```